# toppings in pizza factory?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Going through Head First Design Patterns, and their [Pizza factory example](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-design/0596007124/ch04.html), it seems that there is no room for specifying toppings.

In general, if I have a process which contacts different APIs which right now all take same input parameters, but in the future one of them might change to require more or less parameters, I am wondering how I would handle that. Are there any patterns for that?

Comment: The Decorator Pattern? :)

Comment: I'm not sure if Pizza is necessarily the best illustration or metaphor for inheritance in a real-world problem.   Toppings on a pizza seem as if they'd be best represented as plain data in a list (composition), since OO and particularly inheritance are really all about different behaviours or different ways of your program "doing things" (usually identified using verbs), but Cheese, Pepperoni, Tomato, etc are all *nouns*.   It's a bit odd to imagine different pizza toppings representing variations in a program's behaviour (i.e. different methods for Onions vs Peppers etc.)

Comment: To be fair, classes are *nouns.*  Their *methods* are verbs.

Comment: I built a point of sale system very very early in my career. I've learned a lot since then, but one thing I would not change: Menu items were not encoded in the type system. The type system had generic "menu item" entities, and the actual definitions of the items were *just data*... I guess the lesson there is: Don't make your interfaces *overly* specific. Leave room for things that will *reasonably* change in the next 12 months.

Comment: @BenCottrell: I don't think the storage of the toppings themselves are the focal point of the pizza example though. It's more related to how the concrete pizza types are set in stone at compile time, which allows for the existence of a factory that instantiates these concrete types. OP's idea of dynamically adding/removing toppings actually violates that premise, as those dynamic toppings are a runtime (not compile time) consideration.

Comment: @BenCottrell: _"It's a bit odd to imagine different pizza toppings representing variations in a program's behaviour"_ If you want a real world example, the type of cheese you use on a pizza actually changes the recommended oven temperature. So can certain types of meat (if you expect them to still be cooked, or if you want to prevent them drying out). So there are real behaviors you could steer using the toppings, though I still have to find a real world pizza place than actually cares about this.

Comment: Books and courses often don't do a good job at discriminating between *real-world examples that demonstrate effective use* of something and *toy examples that demonstrate the mechanics* of something. I love HF books but they strongly lean into the latter. If it isn't clear: **This is not meant to be an example of a good way to design software for a pizza shop.** This is a toy example that uses pizza as a **metaphor** for a real-world object, that might be a `ButtonClickEvent` or a `DateRange` or some other kind of object that might appear in real code.

Answer (score 5):

> It seems that there is no room for specifying toppings

The pizza factory from the post you linked is built on the assumption that **types of pizza are known and set in stone at compile time**. This means that you cannot (at runtime) ask for extra/removed toppings, because that violates the basic premise that a pizza's toppings are defined purely by its concrete type.

In other words, this pizza place only allows you to order off the menu. You can't have a `CheesePizza` with no cheese, or with extra pepperoni. You can only choose from the premade pizza options on the menu, and no deviations are allowed.

The only way to have another type of pizza is for the restaurant to put it on the menu (i.e. develop a concrete `RizPizza` class for it).

> In general, if I have a process which contacts different APIs which right now all take same input parameters, but in the future one of them might change to require more or less parameters

It is unclear to me how this question relates to the "extra topping" idea you just discussed.

Toppings are, by their very nature of referring to them as "toppings" and not individually listing each possible topping, a reusable component. Even if you had a `MakeYourOwnPizza` class, you'd expect it to take a `IEnumerable<Topping>` input, rather than a `Cheese`, `Meat`, `Sauce` input.

The latter wouldn't make much sense. What if you wanted multiple meats? What if you wanted no meat? It makes no sense to explicitly enshrine the specific topping types, when you're trying to make a pizza that can take *any and all* kinds of toppings.

This feels like you're building off of the assumption that you can hardcode all possible combinations. It's a futile effort, and much easier to simply allow all combinations using a single implementation.

> In the future one of them might change to require more or less parameters, I am wondering how I would handle that. Are there any patterns for that?

It's not about how to handle it. Handling it is pretty straightforward: You need X to become Y, therefore you change X to Y, and then you check if there is a Z out there that depended on X and needs to adapt to now depending on Y.

But changing X to Y isn't fun and a common source of bugs and redesign, so the aim of the game becomes figuring out how to **avoid having to make changes**, rather than figure out how to handle changes.

This isn't really a design pattern. It's just plain and simple **abstraction**.

By abstracting concrete toppings such as pepperoni, mozzarella cheese, BBQ sauce, cheddar cheese and onions into a reusable abstraction called `Topping`, you ensure that you don't *have* to change the input to your API. Even if you change the toppings on the pizza, it's still going to be the same abstracted `Pizza CreateCustomPizza(IEnumerable<Topping> toppings)` interface.

You don't create a calculator like this:

```
int OnePlusOne()        { return 1 + 1; }
int OnePlusTwo()        { return 1 + 2; }
int TwoPlusOne()        { return OnePlusTwo(); }
int TwoPlusTwo()        { return 2 + 2; }
int OnePlusOnePlusOne() { return OnePlusOne() + 1; }
```

You create a calculator like this:

```
int Add(int[] numbers) { return numbers.Sum(); }
```

If feels like your question about the toppings is based on an idea akin to the first example, rather than the second one.